# Python Guessing Words Game

Tags: python, string

Currently, me and my teamate is running on a small exercise call Guessing Word Games. However, when we run this function. It does not show the right output that meet the teacher expectation. We are stuck with def check_letter also. Therefore, i wonder if you guys can check it for me if i have done anything wrongly:

```
import random




def read_word_list(word_list):
   str_list = []
     for line in word_list:
        for s in line.split():
           try:
              x= str(s)
              str_list.append(x)
           except ValueError:
              pass
        return str_list

words = ["introduction", "programming", "database", "concepts", "techniques", "security"]
my_list = read_word_list(words)
random_word = random.choice(my_list)
blanks = '_ ' * len(random_word)
print()
print ("Word: ",blanks)

def greetings():
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    print("Welcome,", name + "!")
    return name


def read_char(prompt, first, last):
    x= input(prompt)
    while x < first or x > last:
         print("Not in range. Try Again!!!")
         x= input(prompt)
    return x



def check_letters(target, letters):

    print(len(random_word))
    count = 0
    for c in random_word:
       if "a" <= c <= "z":
            count += 1
    print(count)

    count2 = 0
    for i in range(len(random_word)):
        if "a" <= random_word[i] <= "z":
            count2 += 1
    print(count2)

    new_s = " "
    for c in random_word:
        if "a" <= c <= "z" or "A" <= c <= "Z":
            new_s += c
        else:
            new_s += "_"
    print(new_s)
```

Expected Output:

```
Guess a word game.
What is your name? David
 Welcome David!
 7 letters in the word to guess.
 Maximum of 10 attempts.
 Word to guess: _______
 Letters already guessed:
 10 failed attempts left.
Guess a letter: e
Found 1 e.
Word to guess: ______e
Letters already guessed: e
10 failed attempts left. Guess a letter: a
# Didn't find any a
Word to guess: ______e
Letters already guessed: ae
9 failed attempts left.
Guess a letter: i
Didn't find any i
Word to guess: ______e
....
2 failed attempts left.
Guess a letter: l
Didn't find any l
Word to guess: a__e__i__
Letters already guessed: abcdefghijkl
1 failed attempts left.
Guess a letter: m
Didn't find any m
You lose! The word was: attention
Do you want to play again? n
```

Actual Output:

```
Word:  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
Guess a word game.
What is your name? David
Welcome, David!

Please make a guess: a
guess is wrong! 9 more failed attempts allowed.
guess is wrong! 8 more failed attempts allowed.
guess is wrong! 7 more failed attempts allowed.
guess is wrong! 6 more failed attempts allowed.
guess is wrong! 5 more failed attempts allowed.
guess is wrong! 4 more failed attempts allowed.
guess is wrong! 3 more failed attempts allowed.
guess is wrong! 2 more failed attempts allowed.
guess is wrong! 1 more failed attempts allowed.
guess is wrong! 0 more failed attempts allowed.
guess is wrong! -1 more failed attempts allowed.
guess is wrong! -2 more failed attempts allowed.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/Exercise 4/testing.py", line 106, in <module>
    print("Words: ", newBlanks)
NameError: name 'newBlanks' is not defined
```

Comment: There are many things wrong in your program. It wouldn't practical to even list them all here. I suggest talking with your teacher to understand what exactly your doing wrong, and how to meet his expectations. Also, you and your buddy should take a look at the ['official' Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/), to get a better idea of how to write idiomatic Python code.

Comment: I 'd like to but tomorrow is deadline... We donot have time to meet and ask for advice from teacher anymore. Also, we have followed the same structure as he has guided us. However, the key point if in def check_letter, we still dont know how to execute it